# Stanford Glove : Dimension anomaly in glove.twitter.27B.200d

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec

I downloaded Glove-twitter pretrained vectors from http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.twitter.27B.zip

When I load the vectors (using glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt) in memory I find 900 words, whose vectors are of 199 dimensions, while for rest of all the words,  whose vectors are of 200 dimensions.  **As per my understanding - every vector in this file is supposed to be of exactly 200 dimensions. No ?**

I am using the following python code to arrive at my conclusion

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

glove_model_path = './glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt'

f = open(glove_model_path,'r')

model = {}
counter = 0

vary_length = 0
anamolies = []

for line in f:
    counter += 1
    items = line.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').split(' ')
    word = items[0]
    vect = np.array([float(i) for i in items[1:] if len(i) > 1])
    if (len(vect) != 200):
        vary_length += 1
        anamolies.append(word)

f.close()

print vary_length
```

---

```
Output is : 900
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, every vector should be 200 elements.

To elaborate, I suspect the problem is in your code, specifically:

`items = line.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').split(' ')`

Why don't you print those any of those 900 lines and see what they look like. Depending on how tokenization was done, you may have situations where \r or \n is being treated as a word and so you are eliminating some elements. I find it odd though, that the whitespace wouldn't have been merged together by default.

Also, you may want to check if the API to read in those vectors rather than rolling your own. Your code is making some formatting assumptions that may be incorrect.

Comment: To load the vectors I used the code from here       [links] https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/issues/18